# javascript header not displaying on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, rendering

**With Chrome 36**:
[image: Chrome 36]

**With FF 31.0**:
[image: FF 31]

**Live demo**: http://raphaelmartin.github.io/PDC2014/

Why this big difference between the 2 browsers? Is there any workaround? It seems the problem comes from Javascript handling, but I'm not enough good at JS to point out what's wrong.

Comment: clear cache and then try its working for me in firefox also..

Comment: @DevendraSoni already done, but same problem. Well, maybe you're right, it's just my computer. Strange anyway.